# Scala macros: Emit for comprehensions from macros

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros

Trying to emit a `for yield` block from a blackbox macro, but I'm failing to understand how you can create the block with valid syntax.

So below `source` is a hardcoded param name as this block is later inserted inside a method that will have the matching param name. `params` is just `params: Seq[c.universe.ValDef]`, enclosing the `case class` fields.

```
def extract(source: Source): Option[CaseClass] = { ... }

val extractors = accessors(c)(params) map {
  case (nm, tpe) => {
    val newTerm = TermName(nm.toString + "Opt")
    q"""$newTerm <- DoStuff[$tpe].apply("$nm", source)"""
  }
}

val extractorNames = accessors(c)(params) map {
  case (nm, tpe) => TermName(nm.toString + "Opt")
}
```

This is basically taking a `case class`, and outputting a for yield black to basically recreate the case class from a comprehension.

Every field in the case class of the form `name: Type` is transformed to a set of extractors that yield the same case class instance back if the for comprehension is successful.

```
case class Test(id: Int, text: String)
```

Will be macro transformed to the following, where `Extract` is just a type class and `Extract.apply[T : Extract]` is just materialising the context bound with `implicitly[Extract[T]]`:

```
for {
  idOpt <- Extract[Int].apply("id", source): Option[Int]
  textOpt <- Extract[String].apply("text", source): Option[String]
} yield Test(idOpt, textOpt)
```

The problem comes in having to quote the inner for yield expressions with and output `a <- b` blocks.

```
def extract(source: Source): Option[$typeName] = {
  for {(..$extractors)} yield $companion.apply(..$extractorNames)
}
```

The error is `';' expected but '<-' found`, which is pretty obvious as `a <- b` is invalid Scala by itself. What is the correct way to generate and quasiquote the expression block such that the above would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/quasiquotes/syntax-summary.html) is a list of all the different kinds of quasiquotes.
There you can see that to express the `a <- b` syntax you need the `fq` interpolator.
So that code will probably become:

```
val extractors = accessors(c)(params) map {
  case (nm, tpe) => {
    val newTerm = TermName(nm.toString + "Opt")
    fq"""$newTerm <- DoStuff[$tpe].apply("$nm", source)"""
  }
}
```

And then with the normal interpolator:

```
q"for (..$extractors) yield $companion.apply(..$extractorNames)"
```

Comment: Yep found it in the mean time, this is the one. Many thanks!

Comment: Forgot to add `{}` wrappers are not necessary, compiler doesn't like them. the `()` are enough. Just modifying for whoever else will come to this answer in the future.